# All imports in WebStorm shown as unused at TypeScript backend project

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, nestjs, webstorm

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0yZw.png
This is how it looks for all files with `.ts`. And in `.tsx` files it also doesn't work.

Other projects in WebStorm work correct but they're written in `.js` and `.jsx` only.

Also I've tried reinstall WebStorm twice and set all to defaults, that doesn't help at all.

Comment: They show as unused because they are unused, at least in your snippet.

Comment: @StevenSpungin i am using AppService as type

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a .eslintrc.js file?
If not, try adding one so that Webstorm understands what is going on:

```
module.exports = {
parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
parserOptions: {
  project: 'tsconfig.json',
  sourceType: 'module',
},
plugins: ['@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'],
extends: [
  'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
  'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
  'plugin:prettier/recommended',
],
root: true,
env: {
  node: true,
  jest: true,
},
ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],
rules: {
  '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'off',
  '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
  '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
  '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
},
};
```

Also make sure you have typescript enabled in preferences as well (see my image).
[image]

Good luck!

Comment: `module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: 'tsconfig.json',
    tsconfigRootDir : __dirname, 
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['prettier'],
  extends: [
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],
  rules: {
    'no-console': 1,
    'prettier/prettier' : 0,
  },
};`   This is my .eslintrc.ts file also TypeScript enabled

Answer (score 0):

One more set to defaults helps me. Ty all

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).